# why DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED sends multiple messages?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need a single system message on any device insertion into the system. please any one tell which system message to use for example DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL but problem is that DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL does not give message on any non media device like network device or printer connection. DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED gives multiple messages on insertion and removal but I need a single message just on insertion.

Comment: If you are getting multiple `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` messages then multiple devices must be getting added/removed. `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` itself does not give you any information about whether the notification is a add or a remove, or which device(s) are affected. If you read the documentation, it tells you to use [`RegisterDeviceNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) to get that kind of information. You will just have to filter out what you don't want.

Comment: @Remy could you please guide me how can I filter out these kind of messages?

Comment: When any external device is inserted to or removed from system, all nodes [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554721(v=vs.85).aspx] of the system is refreshed or reset. that's why DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED send multiple messages.

Comment: Exact same problem for USB devices. A single device-connection op triggers `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` multiple times.